# MAILTO in crontab

Tags: cron, ssmtp, mta, firejail

My MTA is ssmtp. In crontab I have set the MAILTO line to my email address. What is the actual command that the MAILTO line triggers? Is it possible to modify it? I actually need to start ssmtp as `firejail --net=wlp1s0 ssmtp ....` instead of mere `ssmtp ....`

Comment: I think cron uses the default `sendmail` command. However, how you start ssmtp has nothing to do with this.

Comment: @ArturMeinild, thank you. Here's what I actually need, just so you better understand my conundrum: I need cron to send an email every time it triggers a job, and that email needs to be sent out via a specific wireless network interface. I figured I'd use firejail to bind ... whatever application it is that cron uses to send email to that specific network interface. I am pretty sure that my MTA is ssmtp.